# Firebaseauth nullpointexception

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

> I solved this problem , this error is because of genymotion. If you
>   take this error , you should to use android default emulator

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
```

This line returned to me nullpointexception. how can i solve it?;

```
private FirebaseAuth mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,sifre).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {
            Intent anaekran = new Intent(UyeOl.this,AnaEkran.class);
            startActivity(anaekran);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(UyeOl.this,"Tekrar deneyein",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        loading.dismiss();
    }
});
```

exception;

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                        at anonimchat.UyeOl.RegisterAccount(UyeOl.java:64)
>                                                        at anonimchat.UyeOl.access$300(UyeOl.java:22)
>                                                        at anonimchat.UyeOl$1.onClick(UyeOl.java:48)
>                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I tried something and edit my post , can you see again?

Comment: My error still continue